# Does epoll have exponential backoff?

Tags: tcp, epoll

I have an application that, when it has data to transmit, uses epoll to know whether a given TCP socket can be written to.

What I'm observing is that as the far-end of the TCP connection falls behind, and the send buffer of the TCP socket begins to fill, the frequency with which epoll returns an EPOLLOUT event appears to experience exponential backoff.  This behavior happens prior to receiving an EAGAIN from the socket write.

The application is using EPOLLONESHOT, and makes an EPOLL_CTL_MOD call to rearm the EPOLLOUT event after each occurrence.  But as I noted above, each subsequent occurrence is exponentially later (I had a progression of 40ms, 80ms, 160ms, 320ms, 640ms, 1280ms, etc), up until EAGAIN finally happens.

Is this an undocumented feature of epoll?  Can it be disabled?  It's a problem because the data is getting stale and I would prefer to discard it rather than send it late.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If stale data is a concern, use UDP not TCP; that's why the two protocols were invented.

Answer (score 1):

No, but TCP does. `epoll()` blocks for at most the timeout you specify, and not a moment longer.

Comment: Yes, and the timeout is working fine.  The problem is that the EPOLLOUT event is somehow affected by TCP backoff.  Remember, my application hasn't yet gotten an EAGAIN result from a write, so there is no sign of congestion, yet the EPOLLOUT event for the next write is getting exponentially delayed.

Comment: I don't see why you're using `epoll()` at all when the send buffer isn't full. Just do the write. You should only be going to `epoll()` *after* you get *EAGAIN*, and stop using it when that stops happening.

Comment: Yes, I've already considered this change.  It's not trivial though.  Instead of an alternative implementation, I'd really like to understand why this behavior is occurring in the first place.